# Excel VBA Print margin seems to be ignored

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to set the margin for my print section. When I execute the marco the print preview always pops up with default margins, and not with the margin I have set.

```
'Setup print stuff, print and delete the worksheet
With newSheet
    With PageSetup
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .BlackAndWhite = True
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
    End With
    'Use PrintPreview for Debugging
    .PrintPreview
    .Delete
End With
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using:

```
    With .PageSetup
```

instead of

```
    With PageSetup
```

*Later edit*

The nested `With .PageSetup` will refer to the `PageSetup` property of the outer `With` object (i.e. `newSheet`). Without the dot, one refers a PageSetup property that might apply to some other (currently active) object.

More on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx (the last example)

Comment: Will try this tomorrow! thx a lot, sounds like this is the problem!